# How do I know what component make to use in createTheme components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In looking through the doc for [createTheme's](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/) component object they have examples with MuiButtonBase, MuiButton, and MuiSlider but if you want a button it's just  [Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/) not MuiButton.

Ok so I can guess to just prefix Mui to whatever I want to use and move on, right? Well, no. What about if I want to apply a different level of padding to all the cells of a [devexpress grid cell](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/reference/table/#tablecellprops)? How do I know what component to use in my createTheme components object?

Answer (score 0):

Mui’s theme can inherently theme mui components because those components have been built to know about Mui’s ThemeContext. Your other components don’t know about mui’s ThemeContext and won’t “automatically” be themed by any configuration you add to createTheme.

What you want to do is to approach it from the perspective of the component you want to theme, not the other way around.

In your example, you want to pass a custom component to stubCellComponent on the table and, in that stub component, use useTheme to apply the padding that you want that you have encoded in the theme that you passed to createTheme